# Get the path "to" vs "of" vs "for" a file?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, to-for, for-to-complementizers, of-for

Which phrase would be most correct to use?
Or are they all correct, and it just depends on the situation, which to use?

In my case it's regarding getting a path from a method in a Java program.

> A method to get the path **to** the file.

vs

> A method to get the path **of** a file.

vs

> A method to get the path **for** a file.

Comment: In computer technology, all terms are metaphorical. Are you talking about an address or a set of instructions to reach it?

Comment: file path: https://medium.com/@Linda_Ikechukwu/understanding-file-paths-165c07ec5cf0///A method to return the file path, for example.

Comment: What is the method's functionality? "For" would mean "corresponding to." "To" would be used with relative paths; "of" seems more likely with absolute ones.

Comment: (Also, files can have multiple paths due to hardlinks, but I digress...)

Comment: @alphabet there is no need in computerese to use: path of, to, or for the file. The term is just "file path". Like: door handle, as opposed to handle of the door. Same idea.

Comment: @Lambie Not if "the file" is intended to refer to some specific file mentioned earlier in the text; you'd need "the path of the file" or "the file's path."

Comment: @alphabet No, in AmE computerese the file path is the file's path.

Comment: @Lambie I'm an SWE and US native. If there's some specific file you're discussing, you would refer to it as "the file," so you wouldn't use "file" as a noun adjunct, you'd use "the file" as a possessive.

Comment: @alphabet Of course but that was not the point here: I repeat, in computerese they say file path, they do not say: path of the file, path for the file or path to the file. It's so simple, really. And if it is an earlier file, you just say the the earlier file.

Comment: "to" is better with a relative path ("relative path to a file" is probably the most likely time to say "path to/etc a file"), for absolute any would do.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about the usage or selection of prepositions, I would say that ***to*** is always suitable for the context. Under the presupposition or implication that there is only one path for a certain file, ***for*** is fine too.

Answer (score 2):

A method to get the path **of** the file.

**Of** = that is contextually associated with - compare "The key of the door."

A method to get the path **to** a file.

**to** = that is towards; that is in the direction of; that is functionally associated with - compare "The key to the door."

A method to get the path **for** a file.

**for** = that is for the purpose or benefit of a file - compare "The key **for** the door."